# How to switch back to a view controller without losing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iCarousel view, which for those of you who don't know what it is, works a lot like UITableView or UICollectionView. If you'd like, we can pretend that I'm using one of those.

Anyways, my iCarousel has a bunch of items in it already. They're defined in a global NSMutableArray by the name of "items". My problem is when I switch views for a minute away from the carousel, when i switch back, the items are gone. I believe this is because when i switch views, the carousel is deallocated or the reference is lost. When i try to reload it, i use this code:

```
self.carousel = [[iCarouselExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iCarouselExampleViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:self.carousel animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.carousel.carousel reloadData];
```

This code brings me to an empty carousel. I assume this is because, as aforementioned, i lost the reference to the view and i had to reallocate it with the initWithNibName call. Anyways, how do i get around that? I dont want to lose the data that was in the class. any suggestions? And how would i go about switching back to a UITableView from a different view controller in the first place?

Comment: But didn't you say the items are defined in a global `NSMutableArray`? That's the idea behind separating the view from the data source. Even if your iCarousel view gets deallocated you can still have a reference to the information (items) that populate it.

Comment: the mutable array is stored in the icarousel view controller class so if the view controller goes away so does the items. and when i say global i mean its defined in the .h file

Comment: Well, then store the data source somewhere else. You can consider using CoreData for that. Or if you don't want to have to deal with that, declare the `NSMutableArray` in the AppDelegate or somewhere similar that you know that won't get deallocated. Another option would be to create a Singleton for it. There are many many options.

Comment: If you use above code, it will always creates the new carousel.  create the carousal only if its not available. i.e if(self.carousel == nil) { // create the carousal}

Comment: i see, thank you. if i dont specifically say that carousel is nil then it should be allocated already? also, if somebody puts the answer down then ill accept it

Comment: Yes if its not nil means its already allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object that holds the items that populate your iCarousel gets deallocated you can store the data source somewhere else. You can consider using CoreData for that. Or if you don't want to have to deal with that, declare the NSMutableArray in the AppDelegate or somewhere similar that you know that won't get deallocated. Another option would be to create a Singleton for it. There are many many options.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you create the carousal while presenting it will deallocates the existing one and creates the new one. I don't think for your case it needs to be allocated every time you are presenting.

```
if(self.carousel == nil) {
   self.carousel = [[iCarouselExampleViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"iCarouselExampleViewController" bundle:nil];
}
[self presentViewController:self.carousel animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.carousel.carousel reloadData];
```